# Derivative of $u ^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In Gilbert Strang's Calculus, section 2.5, the author explains the power rule of derivative by giving the example of change in volume of a cube. For cube of side u i.e. $u^3$, the derivative is $3u^2$. However for a change in side of $\Delta u$, the actual change in volume is $3u^2 \Delta u + 3u(\Delta u)^2 + \Delta u ^3$. So, what happens to the last two terms when we look at the rate of change i.e. the derivative. Are they ignored as $\Delta u$ is small and any powers of it would be smaller still?

Comment: You missed out a factor of 3 in the middle term. If you go back to the definition of the derivative, you're dividing by $\Delta u$ then taking the limit as $\Delta u \to 0$, so the higher order terms that remain after the division vanish.

Comment: Yep. That seems very obvious now. Duh! Thank you Deepak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Deepak. By the definition of derivative, once the terms are divided by $\Delta u$ and limit taken, only term left is $3u^2$.

Comment: Deepak added the answer as a comment. So i could not accept it. I have added an answer but I can it accept after two days.